# How to clear the first key press immediately after the short dialog box,if it is a wrong entry in a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm checking the user ID in the text box. And it can not start with a letter or digit '0'. I can catch the wrong entry and send a message to the screen. But the wrong entry will be in the text box until I hit another key. And if this is an acceptable digit then the wrong entry stays at the beginning of the string. So I need to get rid of the wrong entry immediately after the message dialog box. Any suggestion?

```
  private void TxtUserID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {

            MessageBox.Show(" Your User ID can not begin with a letter !!!");
            //txtUserID.Text = string.Empty;
            txtUserID.Clear();
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '0')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your User ID can not begin with 0 !!!");

            txtUserID.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }// end of keypress
```

Comment: You don't want to use `KeyPress` event to check user inputs. User can copy/paste too.

Comment: Id have suggested keydown, but you also want to only check if its the first character.. I assume 0 etc is allowed later.

Comment: That is correct. 0 can be used in the coming digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `TextChanged` instead of `KeyPress` event: *whatever* changed `TxtUserID.Text` (e.g. *Paste*, or, imagine, user put `"12340"` and then *deleted* `"1234"` in order to obtain `"0"`) validate the `TxtUserID`

```
private static bool IsNameValid(string name) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    return true;
  else if (name.Any(c => c < '0' || c > '9')) {
    MessageBox.Show("Your User ID must contain digits only!");

    return false;
  }
  else if (name.StartsWith("0")) {
    MessageBox.Show("Your User ID must not start from 0!");

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

private void TxtUserID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsNameValid(TxtUserID.Text))
    txtUserID.Clear(); // Taken from the question
}
```

**Edit:** As *Thomas Voß* pointed out, *clearing* the entire text can be to cruel for a user (imagine that he's printed `"1001234566978563"` and then decided to remove leading `"100"`), probably

```
    txtUserID.Text = string.Concat(txtUserID
      .Text
      .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') // Digits only
      .SkipWhile(c => c == '0'));       // Trim all starting '0'
```

instead of `txtUserID.Clear();` when we remove all characters but digits and trim leadibng `0` is a better choice.

Comment: Using the clear method will work, but it is not nice as the text will be cleared if you have a letter at any position in the text. Imagine pressing o instead of 0 in the last position of the user id. What you can do instead is you can use the SubString method to delete the last char again. `txtUserId.Text = txtUserId.SubString(0, txtUserId.Length - 1);`

Comment: @Thomas Voß: yes, I've just adapted the existing code. Frankly speaking, I would not show message on non-digit keys, but ignore them; I silently trim leading / trailing whitespaces (what if user copy and paste id with some spaces); yes `Clear()` can well appear too rude for a user, probably `txtUserID.Text = string.Concat( txtUserID.Text.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9').SkipWhile(c => c == '0'));` is a better choice